# Can't update SendGrid Single Send associated lists using the API

Tags: php, api, sendgrid

I'm using the latest SendGrid PHP API. I can successfully create a Single Send using the API, and easily associate lists the Single Send should go to when it's eventually scheduled (by list ID). When I use the API to then update that Single Send to use different lists, the list changes are not reflected in the SendGrid dashboard - only name changes, etc. The API request is successful in code and when using Postman. SendGrid's API response to the update reflects my changes in what they return back to me. The Single Send is also in "draft mode" when I attempt this. The associated lists in the SendGrid dashboard never change.

API call to Single Send Update Endpoint (PATCH):

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/singlesends/3ee0cd4e-62f7-21eb-8ee8-3a2e1ebc21ed
```

with param:

```
{
    "name": "TESTER 2",
    "send_to": {
        "list_ids": [
            "52ca8ad3f-9db1-4c2x-1f01-85beecbx94c2"
        ]
    }
}
```

And SendGrid returns (202, successful response code):

```
{
    "id": "3ee0cd4e-62f7-21eb-8ee8-3a2e1ebc21ed",
    "name": "TESTER 2",
    "status": "draft",
    "categories": [],
    "send_at": "2021-02-01T19:06:00Z",
    "send_to": {
        "list_ids": [
            "52ca8ad3f-9db1-4c2x-1f01-85beecbx94c2"
        ],
        "segment_ids": [],
        "all": false
    },
    "updated_at": "2021-01-31T22:52:58Z",
    "created_at": "2021-01-31T19:07:20Z",
    "email_config": {
        "subject": "Hello World",
        "html_content": "Hello World!",
        "plain_content": "Hello World!",
        "generate_plain_content": false,
        "editor": "code",
        "suppression_group_id": null,
        "custom_unsubscribe_url": "https://www.example.org/unsubscribe",
        "sender_id": 1212111,
        "ip_pool": null
    }
}
```

But, the associated contact lists are **not** updated. Anyone have any suggestions? My only workaround is to simply delete the single send every time and just re-create it. I'm storing their ID's locally so this adds a bit more work on my end, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling with this, hopefully this will save you some time. The problem wasn't with the API at all, but with the SendGrid dashboard. You need to do a hard reload on the Single Send dashboard page to see your changes. The SendGrid dashboard is a SPA. Ugh.